# Multiple joins in linq

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, join

I just learned how the work with asp.net and I am trying to write a linq-statement with multiple join, but I dont seem to make it work.

I have 4 tables:

- Competition (wich contains multiple rounds)
- Round (which has multiple entries)
- Entry (Which can appear be in multiple rounds)
- RoundEntry (which contains the primairy keys of Round and Entry to combine them)

I want to you enter the page competition.aspx I want to display the entered entries within the different rounds.

Can someone help me with the statement, as well a suggestion how to build up my page.

Comment: Please add the fields in each of your tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have data context named `db` and tables have keys named `Id`.

```
var entries = from e in db.Entry
              join re in db.RoundEntry on e.Id equals re.EntryId
              join r in db.Round on re.RoundId equals r.Id
              select e;
```